# Visual SVN Server security hole - attempts in trying to find files on our server

Tags: windows-server-2008, visualsvn-server

Looking through my VisualSVNServer logs, I'm seeing several attempts from different client IP addresses trying to find files on the server.

E.g. here is the logged events showing that someone tried to access non-existent files (*was searching for vulnerabilities*):

```
Log Name:      VisualSVNServer
Source:        VisualSVN Server 2.1
Date:          1/2/2012 8:05:23 AM
Event ID:      1001
Task Category: Apache
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      MYSERVER
Description:
File does not exist: C:/Program Files (x86)/VisualSVN Server/htdocs/phpmyadmin
[client 87.106.128.38]
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="VisualSVN Server 2.1" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1001</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>2</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-01-02T13:05:23.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>716</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>VisualSVNServer</Channel>
    <Computer>MYSERVER</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>File does not exist: C:/Program Files (x86)/VisualSVN Server/htdocs/phpmyadmin
</Data>
    <Data>87.106.128.38</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

How can I avoid this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Windows Firewall to limit access to VisualSVN Server only from trusted networks.

Comment: In addition to this, SVN Server admin/Networking gives you the ability to lock down the IP address and PORT for incoming connections.